# Add linux program to list of "other applications" for opening files from Nautilus

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

I have installed a markdown editor on ubuntu 12.0.4:

```
sudo dpkg -i /shared/mdcharm_1.1.6_i386.deb
sudo apt-get  -f install   # Installed missing dependencies
```

Is the md editor installed now?

```
steve@mithril:/d/hwspark/docs$ which mdcharm
/usr/bin/mdcharm    # Installation successful!
```

***But*** the mdcharm does NOT show up in "Other applications" from the right click/open menu on Nautilus.  How to add it manually?

Comment: @don_crissti  Looks to be correct way. Feel free to make it a real answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Nautilus is looking for applications in `/usr/share/applications` and `~./local/share/applications` and lists only those apps that match your file mime type. You should try to create a launcher (`.desktop` file) for your program if you want to see it in that list. Make sure your launcher includes the specific mimetype for your files (`text/plain` and `text/x-markdown` come to mind but you could run `file --mime-type myfile.md` or `gvfs-info -a standard::content-type myfile.md` and check the output).